# Vector spaces - Multiplying by $-1$ yields inverse element of vector addition.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, proof-verification, learning

Please rate and comment. I want to improve; constructive criticism is highly appreciated.
Please take style into account as well.

The following proof is based on vector space related axioms.
Axiom names are *italicised*.
They are defined in Wikipedia (see vector space article).
Additionally, [this trivial result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893350/138360) is used.

### Multiplying by $-1$ yields inverse element of vector addition.

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$.
\begin{array}{lrll}
\text{By} & \dots & \text{we denote} & \dots \\
\hline
& 1          && \text{a multiplicative identity element in $F$.} \\
& (-1)       && \text{an additive inverse of $1$ in $F$.} \\
& 0          && \text{an additive identity element in $F$.} \\
& \mathbf{0} && \text{an additive identity element in $V$.} \\
\end{array}
Let $\mathbf{v} \in V$.
We want to prove that
$$(-1)\mathbf{v} \text{ is an additive inverse of } \mathbf{v} \text{ in } V.$$
*Proof.* We prove that $\mathbf{v} + (-1)\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$.
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{v} + (-1)\mathbf{v}
 &= 1\mathbf{v} + (-1)\mathbf{v} && \text{by }\textit{Identity element of scalar multiplication} \\
 &= (1 + (-1))\mathbf{v}         && \text{by }\textit{Distrib. of scalar mult. (field addition)} \\
 &= 0\mathbf{v}                  && \text{by }\textit{Inverse elements of field addition} \\
 &= \mathbf{0}                   && \text{by the result linked above}
\end{align*}
QED

Comment: Yeah, that's fine

Comment: Your proof is good. I will just comment that in the right-hand column in your table, all four "a"/"an" should be "the", because the three identities and -1 are all unique.

Comment: @Bungo I did not use "the" because uniqueness is not explicit in the axioms (in Wikipedia).

Comment: @draco - OK, fair enough :-)

Comment: i.e. scale $\,\bf v\,$ by $\ 0\, =\, -1 + 1\ \ $