# Vector spaces - Multiplying by zero vector yields zero vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, proof-verification, learning

Please rate and comment. I want to improve; constructive criticism is highly appreciated.
Please take style into account as well.

The following proof is solely based on vector space axioms.
Axiom names are *italicised*.
They are defined in Wikipedia (vector space).

### Multiplying by zero vector yields zero vector.

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$.
Let $a \in F$.
\begin{array}{lrll}
\text{By} & \dots & \text{we denote} & \dots \\
\hline
& (-a)       && \text{an additive inverse of $a$ in $F$.} \\
& 1          && \text{a multiplicative identity element in $F$.} \\
& 0          && \text{an additive identity element in $F$.} \\
& \mathbf{0} && \text{an additive identity element in $V$.} \\
\end{array}
We want to prove that
$$a \mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0}.$$
*Proof.*
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{0}
 &= 1 \mathbf{0}                                    && \text{by }\textit{Identity element of scalar multiplication} \\
 &= (a + (-a)) \mathbf{0}                           && \text{by }\textit{Inverse elements of field addition} \\
 &= a \mathbf{0} + (-a) \mathbf{0}                  && \text{by }\textit{Distrib. of scalar mult. (field addition)} \\
 &= a (\mathbf{0} + \mathbf{0}) + (-a) \mathbf{0}   && \text{by }\textit{Identity element of vector addition} \\
 &= (a \mathbf{0} + a \mathbf{0}) + (-a) \mathbf{0} && \text{by }\textit{Distrib. of scalar mult. (vector addition)} \\
 &= a \mathbf{0} + (a \mathbf{0} + (-a) \mathbf{0}) && \text{by }\textit{Associativity of vector addition} \\
 &= a \mathbf{0} + (a + (-a)) \mathbf{0}            && \text{by }\textit{Distrib. of scalar mult. (field addition)} \\
 &= a \mathbf{0} + 0 \mathbf{0}                     && \text{by }\textit{Inverse elements of field addition} \\
 &= (a + 0) \mathbf{0}                              && \text{by }\textit{Distrib. of scalar mult. (field addition)} \\
 &= a \mathbf{0}                                    && \text{by }\textit{Identity element of field addition}
\end{align*}
QED

Comment: In the 2nd line, you seem to be using $a+(-a)=1$.

Comment: @user84413 Yes, my mistake! :-( Thanks

Comment: ... looks like this can be fixed by replacing 1 with 0 (scalar) in the first line. (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/893350/138360)

Comment: This is all right to do, if you have already shown that $0v=\mathbf{0}$.  You might want to use Andre Nicolas' suggestion, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not $a(\mathbf{0})=a(\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{0})=a(\mathbf{0})+a(\mathbf{0})$; now add the inverse of $a(\mathbf{0})$ to both sides?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about that. Out of personal preference - somehow - I wanted to transform a single term (instead of an identity).

Comment: Unfortunately that calculation had a glitch early on. I do not see any obvious way of keeping the same basic structure.

Comment: What about the fix suggested above?

Comment: Yes, that will work. In a sense it is a longer version of the solution above, since instead of adding the addiive inverse of $a(\mathbf 0)$, you are adding $(-a)(\mathbf{0})$, which is the additive inverse. You are also using a presumably previously proved result $0\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.