# A Scalar times the Zero Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, alternative-proof

I'm reading *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Sheldon Axler and the proof given in the book is the same as the one in the answer provided for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904293/vector-spaces-multiplying-by-zero-vector-yields-zero-vector).

I tried to solve this before looking at the solution and the way I did it was:

> *Theorem:* *$a \cdot \vec0 = \vec 0 $* for every $a \in \mathbb F$

*Proof* $\ $Let $a \in \mathbb F$, then

\begin{align}a \cdot \vec0    
&= a \cdot \langle 0_1,0_2, \ldots ,0_n\rangle \tag{Def. of a vector}\\
&= \langle a \cdot0_1,a \cdot0_2, \ldots ,a \cdot0_n \rangle \tag{Def. of Scalar Multiplication} \\
&= \langle 0_1,0_2,...,0_n \rangle \\
&= \vec 0
\end{align}

Hence,  $a \cdot \vec0 = \vec 0 $ , desired result.

- Is there anything wrong with this proof? For example, I didn't explain why $a \cdot 0_j = 0$, do I have to do so?
- Also doesn't this proof provide more insight in terms of using basic definitions rather than just vector algebra?*
- Is there a way to proof this result besides this and the one given in the link?

Comment: Your proof is limited to one specific vector space. The statement seems valid in an abstract vector space (and even infinite-dimensional) as well.

Comment: $\mathbf{0}\cdot a = (\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{0})\cdot a =...$

Comment: I originally intended to show you how the `align` environment can be used to provide a far superior result with significantly less effort (Note that the ampersand `&` is used to mark the alignment point, while `\\ ` is used for new lines; you can even add `\tag{}`'s). And to use `\langle` and `\rangle` rather than inequalities. And `\ldots` instead of three periods when in mathmode.

Comment: @pjs36 Thanks for that! Do you have any ideas on how the edited version(edited before your edit) might fix the problem of the proof being limited to a specific vector space? Once again thanks

Comment: I guess the idea of the first comment is that it's a fairly heavy theorem that every finite-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to $\Bbb F^n$, for some field $\Bbb F$ and natural number $n$. *This* is what your proof seems to require as a prerequisite, as well as that your space is finite-dimensional. I wouldn't go so far as to say it applies to one vector space, but you have some significant prerequisites/assumptions that aren't actually required for the result to hold.

Comment: @pjs36 Thanks. If you want you can make your comment an answer I'd be glad to select as the correct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that the zero vector is the neutral element for vector addition, so it is equal to itself minus itself. Then use the distributive law for scalar multiplication.

Comment: Can you explain more about how this proof is limited to a specific vector space? Thanks I'm new to this

Comment: Is it because I use the def. of a vector in $ \mathbb F^n$ in the second step? So the method in your answer is a general  $\vec 0 $ in any $ V$?

Comment: Yep, your proof is valid if a coordinate system is given in advance. The group and distributive laws hold in any vector space.