# My first proof related to subspaces (vector spaces). Please comment.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification, proof-writing

What do you think about my first proof which deals with subspaces?

### Theorem

An intersection of subspaces is a subspace.

### Preliminaries

Corresponding to the [notation in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition),
symbols for vectors are $\mathbf{boldized}$, symbols for scalars are not.
Our proof requires a definition of $\textit{subspace}$.
There are several well-known definitions which are equivalent among each other.
We choose [the one found in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Subspaces_and_quotient_spaces):

Let $F$ be a field.
Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$.
Let $W \subseteq V$.
We call $W$ a $\textit{subspace of}$ $V$ iff the following conditions $C1,C2,C3$ hold.

- (C1) $\quad$ $W \ne \emptyset$
- (C2) $\quad$ $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in W \Rightarrow \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} \in W$
- (C3) $\quad$ $\mathrm{a} \in K, \mathbf{a} \in W \Rightarrow \mathrm{a} \mathbf{a} \in W$

### Proof

Let $F$ be a field.
Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$.
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 1$.
Let $I = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$.
Let $(W_i)_{i \in I}$ be a sequence of subspaces of $V$.
Let $\mathfrak{W} = \bigcap_{i \in I} W_i$.
Hereinafter, we prove that $\mathfrak{W}$ is a subspace of $V$.
To that end, we successively check our three conditions.

$\textbf{Checking (C1)}\quad$
Let $i \in I$.
Trivially, $W_i$ meets (C1).
Let $\mathbf{a} \in W_i$.
Trivially, $K$ contains its additive identity element $0$.
We consider the product $0\mathbf{a}$.
Since $W_i$ meets (C3), $0\mathbf{a} \in W_i$.
In [another proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893350/138360), we saw that $0\mathbf{a}$ equals the zero vector of $V$;
we denote this zero vector by $\mathbf{0}$.
All in all, for every $i \in I$, $\mathbf{0} \in W_i$.
Hence, $\mathbf{0} \in \mathfrak{W}$.
Hence, $\mathfrak{W} \ne \emptyset$,
i.e. $\mathfrak{W}$ meets (C1).

$\textbf{Checking (C2)}\quad$
We proved that $\mathfrak{W} \ne \emptyset$.
Let $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathfrak{W}$.
We define $\mathbf{c} := \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b}$.
It remains to prove that $\mathbf{c} \in \mathfrak{W}$.
Let $i \in I$.
Necessarily; $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in W_i$.
Additionally, $W_i$ meets (C2).
Hence, $\mathbf{c} \in W_i$.
All in all, for every $i \in I$, $\mathbf{c} \in W_i$.
Hence, $\mathbf{c} \in \mathfrak{W}$.

$\textbf{Checking (C3)}\quad$
Trivially, $K \ne \emptyset$.
Let $\mathrm{a} \in K$.
Again, we proved that $\mathfrak{W} \ne \emptyset$.
Let $\mathbf{b} \in \mathfrak{W}$.
We define $\mathbf{c} := \mathrm{a} \mathbf{b}$.
It remains to prove that $\mathbf{c} \in \mathfrak{W}$.
Let $i \in I$.
Necessarily, $\mathbf{a} \in W_i$.
Additionally, $W_i$ meets (C3).
Hence, $\mathbf{c} \in W_i$.
All in all, for every $i \in I$, $c \in W_i$.
Hence, $\mathbf{c} \in \mathfrak{W}$.

QED

Comment: It's wordier than it needs to be, and it's not really necessary to set vectors in bold, but the proof looks fine to me.

Comment: Agreed. This is very wordy.

Comment: The only error I see is that 'boldized' isn't a word.

Comment: Thanks! In which sentence does wordiness strike you the most?

Comment: By the way, it is not necessary to use the non-emptyness in the last two parts. If the sets happened to be empty (which they are not) it would be vacuously true that for any $u$ and $v$ the sum is in.

Comment: I used the non-emptiness, because I got into the habit of thinking about non-emptiness before writing down any statement of the form "Let $x \in X$". So non-emptiness is merely intended to be a justification for "Let ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As communicated in the comments, this looks ok but it doesn't need to be so wordy. With your notation, here's how I would prove (C1)-(C3).

Let $I$ be a set and for every $i\in I$ let $W_i$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$. Let $\mathfrak W=\bigcap W_i$.

(C1): Since every $W_i$ is a subspace we have $\mathbf 0\in W_i$ for every $i$. It follows that $\mathbf 0\in\mathfrak W$ so $\mathfrak W\neq\varnothing$.

(C2): $\mathbf a,\mathbf b\in\mathfrak W$ implies $\mathbf a,\mathbf b\in W_i$ for every $i$. But $\mathbf a+\mathbf b\in W_i$ for every $i$ since every $W_i$ is a subspace. Hence $\mathbf a+\mathbf b\in\mathfrak W$.

(C3) Let $a\in K$ and $\mathbf a\in \mathfrak W$. Then $a\mathbf a\in W_i$ for each $W_i$ since each $W_i$ is a subspace. Hence $a\mathbf a\in\mathfrak W$.

One thing to note is that the proof of each ($C_i$) does not assume ($C_j$). In other words, the axioms of subspaces are independent.

Comment: Thanks!
I dont really get the part for (C3).
Should it perhaps start like this?
(C3) $\mathbf a\in\mathfrak W$ implies ...

Comment: Yes. Wasn't 100% sober when I wrote this last night.