# Is the identity scalar axiom needed for the proof that $0\cdot v=\mathbf{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

My instructor said that 
$$0\cdot v=\mathbf{0}$$
**does** need the axiom $1\cdot v=v.
$
Was he wrong or the proof below uses the axiom implicitly ?

> *Proof.* Let $(V,+,\cdot)_F$ be a vector space over the field $F$. We wish to show that $\forall v\in V$ one has $0\cdot v=\mathbf{0}$, where $0$ is the zero scalar and $\mathbf{0}$ is the zero vector. Let $v$ be an element of the vector space $V$;
>
> By one of the axioms of field addition, $$0\cdot v=(0+0)\cdot v.$$
>   Since scalar multiplication is distributive over addition, $$(0+0)\cdot v=0\cdot v+0\cdot v.$$
>   From the previous two equalities we conclude that $$0\cdot v=0\cdot v+0\cdot v.$$ 
>   Adding to both sides the inverse element for addition of $0\cdot v$, which we'll denote by $-0\cdot v$: $$0\cdot v+(-0\cdot v)=0\cdot v+0\cdot v+(-0\cdot v).$$
>   By the inverse axiom, $$\mathbf{0}=0\cdot v+\mathbf{0},$$
>   hence by the identity axiom, $$0\cdot v=\mathbf{0}.\tag*{$\square$}$$
>   https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1694413/503397

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instructor was wrong -- this does not require the *multiplicative* identity axiom,
$$
1 \cdot \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{v},
$$
because as you can see, the scalar $1$ does not occur in the proof you posted.

However it uses the *additive* identity axiom, that is that
$$
\boldsymbol{0} + \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{v}
$$
for all $\boldsymbol{v}$, where $\boldsymbol{0}$ is the zero vector.

Is it possible your instructor meant the additive identity axiom, rather than the multiplicative identity axiom?

Comment: Instructor said that the axiom is required

Comment: @Milan Oh sorry, I misread that. I updated the post.

Comment: Does it also use the additive inverse axiom $\forall \mathbf{v} \,\, \exists  \mathbf{u}=-\mathbf{v}$ such that $\mathbf{v}+(-\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{0}$ ?

Comment: Is it possible your instructor meant the additive identity axiom, rather than the multiplicative identity axiom?

Comment: @Henry Yes, additive inverse axiom is used.