# Is scalar $0$ times a vector $0$ again a scalar zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I wonder if product of scalar $0$ and zero vector $0$ is equal to scalar $0$.

I will write $z := 0 \in V$ to avoid confusion and for $0 \in \mathbb{F}$ notation will stay the same. So, this is what I know:

a) scalar zero times any vector:
$0 \cdot v = z, \forall v \in \mathbb{V}.$ It's easy to prove this: $0 \cdot v = (0 + 0)v = 0v + 0v.$ Adding $-0v$ to both sides we obtain $z = 0v + z$ and thus $z = 0v.$ *(Here we used axiom that $av$ is indeed in $V$ for all $a \in \mathbb{F}, v \in V.$)*

Of course, $v$ can be also a zero vector so $0 \cdot z = z.$

b) Zero vector times any scalar $a \in \mathbb{F}$:
$z \cdot a = a \cdot z = a(z + z) = az + az.$ Simillary as before, adding $-az$ to both sides we get $z = az.$

But this don't *disaprove* that $0v = 0 \in \mathbb{F}, \forall v \in V.$ But if this is in fact true, then it's also $0 = z$, isn't it?

Comment: scalar times vector is always a vector by definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vector spaces - Multiplying by zero scalar yields zero vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893350/vector-spaces-multiplying-by-zero-scalar-yields-zero-vector)

Comment: scalar multiplication is by definition a map $\mathbb F\times V\to V$. It's result is an element of $V$, not of $\mathbb F$, by definition.

Comment: Oh, yes... Thanks