# Linear Algebra: Determine Zero Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $u = (u_1, u_2)$ and $v = (v_1, v_2)$ be any two positive vectors. Define $u + v = (u_1v_1, u_2/v_2)$ and $ku = (u_1^k, ku_2)$.
> (a) Find the zero vector.
> (b) Find $-u$.
> (c) Does $(-1)u = -u$, why?

I was solving this problem. By the operations defined, I got two different zero vectors, one is $(1, 1)$, and another is $(1, u_2^2)$. So, should I say that the zero vector does not exist and hence the following questions could not be solved?

Comment: Of the two zero vectors you've found only the first one does not depend on u.

Comment: Wouldn't your second one give $u+v=(u_1, \frac{1}{u_2})$?

Comment: Are you sure $ku=(u_1^k,ku_2)$ and not $ku = (u_1^k, u_2^k)$

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the revised scalar multiplication operation. And the "addition operation" isn't commutative:

$$\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v} = (u_1v_1,u_2/v_2) \neq \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{u} = (v_1u_1,v_2/u_2)$$

This doesn't sound like a consistent definition.

Additional details below.

---

The zero vector $\mathbf{0}$ is a unique member of the vector space $V$ such that:

1. **Additive identity**: $\forall \mathbf{a}\in V\;\;\;\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{a}= \mathbf{a}$
2. **Scalar multiplication by zero**: $\forall \mathbf{a}\in V\;\;0\mathbf{a}= \mathbf{0}$

So we need to find a vector $\mathbf{0}=(a_1,a_2) \in V$ that gives us:

(1) $(u_1a_1,u_2/a_2) = (u_1,u_2) = (a_1u_1,a_2/u_2)$ and

(2) $(u_1^0,0)=(a_1,a_2)$

$(2)$ uniquely identifies $\mathbf{0}=(1,0)$.

However, $(1,0)$ cannot serve as an additive inverse:

$$\mathbf{0} + \mathbf{u} = (u_1,0)\neq \mathbf{u} \neq \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{0} = (1,\infty)$$

If we fix scalar multiplication to be $k\mathbf{u} = (u_1^k,u_2^k)$ then [scalar multiplication will be consistent with the additive identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893350/vector-spaces-multiplying-by-zero-scalar-yields-zero-vector).

Was there a typo? Also, if $u$ is supposed to be a positive vector

Comment: No, there wasn't any typo. That's why I was confused by the problem. But thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: @Hsunnnnnn -- yeah, I'd clarify with your professor -- something strange about this question.